# How to properly configure sqlite database connection with laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, sqlite

Problem is I can't migrate to sqlite database and already tried search several related problem with no luck. However, when creating fresh laravel app and do the same configuration as I've stated on below steps, no issues encountered and will successfully migrated database schema.

I tried:

> ```
> php artisan config:clear - issue still exist.
>
> composer du -o - issue still exist
>
> php artisan migrate - still nothing happens
> ```

Here is my config in .env :

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
```

And here is my database.php configuration:

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
        'prefix' => '',
       'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
    ],
```

[database migrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTY0V.png)

Here's products migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('barcode')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('unit')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
        $table->double('purchase_price')->default(0.0);
        $table->double('selling_price')->default(0.0);
        $table->double('supply_price')->default(0.0);
        $table->double('taxation')->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('stock_limit')->default(1);
        $table->integer('quantity')->default(0); // This will be updated when adding and removing quantity of the product and should matched in inventory 
        $table->timestamp('expiration')->nullable();
        $table->string('type')->default('stock'); // consignment or stock
        $table->string('attr')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I've created empty database.sqlite with the following command:

```
touch database\database.sqlite
```

Here is the output when try to run php artisan migrate:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: products (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "products" where quantity <= stock_limit)
In PDOConnection.php line 63:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: products 
In PDOConnection.php line 61:
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: products
```

Comment: Show your migrations please. Such query `select count(*) as aggregate from "products" where quantity <= stock_limit` is pretty strange for being executed from migration

Comment: Migrations attached in image

Comment: I meant, we need to know what's inside your migration files.

Comment: @Tarasovych added products table migration.

Comment: You said you're trying to execute `php artisan migrate`. What migrations are already applied at that moment? What about `php artisan migrate:fresh`? Same error? Do you have any DB events-listeners, which may cause the error?

Comment: No migrations applied. That output stated above steps are the only results nothing else.

Comment: Ok, where that query `select count(*)` is coming from than?)